# Search for lines in a file that contain de lines of a second file

Tags: linux, bash

So I have a first file with a ID in each line, for example:

```
458-12-345
466-44-3-223
578-4-58-1
599-478
854-52658
955-12-32
```

Then I have a second file. It has a ID in each file followed by information, for example:

```
111-2457-1 0.2545 0.5484 0.6914 0.4222
112-4844-487 0.7475 0.4749 0.1114 0.8413
115-44-48-5 0.4464 0.8894 0.1140 0.1044
```

....

The first file only has 1000 lines, with the IDs of the info I need, while the second file has more than 200,000 lines.

I used the following bash command in a fedora with good results:

```
cat file1.txt | while read line; do cat file2.txt | egrep "^$line\ "; done > file3.txt
```

However I'm now trying to replicate the results in Ubuntu, and the output is a blank file. Is there a reason for this not to work in Ubuntu?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical job for awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{i[$1]=1;next} i[$1]{print}' file1 file2
```

This will print the lines from the second file that have an index in the first one. For even more speed, use mawk.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly both on the Fedora and on Cygwin, it's also really fast, so that is a great improvement.It didn't work on my Ubuntu, so I believe someting is wrong with it.

Comment: Should work on your Ubuntu. It should even work with the good old 1977 traditional awk. Does it throw any error?

Answer (score 2):

You can grep for several strings at once:

```
grep -f id_file data_file
```

Assuming that **id_file** contains all the IDs and **data_file** contains the IDs and data.

Comment: Nice use of grep but not really appropriate for large files. Just did some testing on a 1000 lines and 200000 lines files and awk is about two times faster.

Answer (score 0):

this line works fine for me in Ubuntu:

```
cat 1.txt | while read line; do cat 2.txt | grep "$line"; done
```

However, this may be slow as the second file (200000 lines) will be grepped 1000 times (number of lines in the first file)